# Power BI not Showing 0 values on Line Graph Creating Breaks in the Line

Tags: powerbi, reporting

I am attempting to get the line graph to show 0 values. The line on the graph should go down from pre-may to 0 in may and then back up from 0 into June. I have created this measure to add 0 values when it does not exist for that month.

```
IF(
 ISBLANK(DISTINCTCOUNT(CASE_V[CASE_NUMBER])),
 0,
 DISTINCTCOUNT(CASE_V[CASE_NUMBER]))
```

I apply the measure to the "Values" for the visual.

My X axis is a date/time column

My Legend is a custom column identifying whether the case is open or close

However, I still receive the same results as below. I have also attempted to use "Show items with no data" but this option does not appear as an option for me.

[image]

[image]